# rvalue reference of std::function<void()>?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, rvalue-reference, stdthread

I'm trying to compile some third party code, which isn't working because it contains a call similar to:

```
void async(std::function<void()> f)
{
    typedef std::function<void()> F;
    auto task_wrapper = [](F&& f){
        f();
        // some other stuff
    };
    std::async(std::launch::deferred, task_wrapper, std::move(f));
}
```

which fails with:

```
error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::function<void (void)>' to 'F &&'
```

I'm hoping someone can explain to me why this fails while other calls using arguments and return types such as the following don't:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
void threadPool::async(std::function<Ret(Args...)> f, Args... args)
{
    typedef std::function<Ret(Args...)> F;
    auto task_wrapper = [](F&& f, Args&&... args){
        f(args...);
        // other stuff
    };

    std::async(std::launch::deferred,
        task_wrapper, std::move(f), std::move(args...));
}
```

**EDIT:**

I encounter this error when compiling with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I do not get any errors with g++ 4.8.2

Comment: VS2013. I was just in the process of checking if gcc worked, thanks for the info.

Comment: I distrust your "call like" claim.  Your second example looks simply wrong (ie, worse code than I'd expect in a library -- it is missing `forward`s for example).  Please generate a simple, reproducable case that fails to compile, instead of pseudo-code.  This is not an invitation to post the entire library: reduce it to a non-compiling simple case.

Comment: @PiotrS. Why not just take it by value and move? There is no need to copy here. (Since C++14 we could indeed use generalized captures)

Comment: also, IIRC the `std::future` from `std::async` waits in the destructor, so you have no benefit from using async call here at all

Comment: @Columbo you mean `[f = std::move(f)]` ?

Comment: @Columbo in VS 2013?

Comment: @PiotrS. With "take by value" I meant the function parameter, not the capture. I suggest not to capture at all here. Since C++14 (and provided you have an appropriate compiler) once could use generalized captures to avoid the copy.

Comment: @Piotrs. `std::async`'s return value does not block in VS2013, as they violated the standard on purpose.  It is still a bad idea to rely on that for many reasons (not the least of which is shutdown).  I'm not sure where you think the dangling reference is?

Comment: @Yakk ok I see that `std::async` makes copies of arguments into the shared state before the thread's execution starts?

Comment: @PiotrS. yes, everything is copied before the function returns, unless you pass by `std::ref` naturally?